# Property is NULL after webservice has been called in WPF application

Tags: wpf, web-services, mvvm, callback

My demo application implements the MVVM pattern in a WPF project. The ViewModel calls a remote webservice via a service agent (proxy) like this:

```
proxy.GetProjectList((sender, e) => this.ProjectList, username, password);
```

`ProjectList` is a property defined in the ViewModel. It holds an array of `CProject` objects. The view binds to this property to display the project names. Basically this works fine.

However I get a `NullReferenceException` if I add the following if-statement:

```
proxy.GetProjectList((sender, e) => this.ProjectList = e.Result, username, password);
if (ProjectList.Length > 0) doSomething();
```

Debugging the application shows that the `ProjectList` property is `null` after the webservice has been called. And I just dont't know why.

The webservice call above is implemented as follows:

```
public void GetProjectList(EventHandler<getProjectListCompletedEventArgs> callback, string username, string password) {
  proxy.getProjectListCompleted += callback;
  proxy.getProjectListAsync(username, password);
}
```

Comment: Is `ProjectList` `null` before calling the webservice?

Comment: Yes it is. This property is set initially by calling the webservice. Funny thing: the control in the UI which is bound to `ProjectList` gets correctly filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the hint from [HighCore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643085/highcore) I changed my implementation to the following.

**Calling the operation from the client:**

```
proxy.GetProjectList(GetProjectListCallback, Username, SecurePassword);
```

**Adding the callback method before:**

```
private void GetProjectListCallback(object sender, getProjectListCompletedEventArgs e) {
  ProjectList = e.Result;
  if (ProjectList != null) {
    if (ProjectList.Length > 0) doSomething();
  }
}
```

**Calling the actual webservice operation in a seperate service agent:**

```
public void GetProjectList(getProjectListCompletedEventArgs callback, string username, SecureString password) {
  proxy.getProjectListCompleted += callback;
  proxy.getProjectListAsync(username, password);
}
```

I don't know if this is a good programming style but it works :-)

Comment: Yes this actually is a way to do it in an async manner. thus making sure your application (UI) does not freeze while waiting for the service call. Notice, however, that you now need to make sure the UI is kept in a state that lets the user know the application is actually doing something (such as a BusyIndicator), and also prevent the user from firing the operation repeatedly (such as disabling buttons and stuff)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint. These things are already next on the list :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Async version of the method. That's why the `ProjectList` property does not immediately get populated after your method call.

I suggest you research a little bit about sync and async.

Also, to make this work, place your if code inside the lambda expression (or otherwise in a separate callback method to be called when the service call is completed)